# FFT division Complex, Java

Tags: java, matlab, fft, division, polynomials

I see this in matlab file.  freqz.m file

```
   h = dividenowarn(fft([b zeros(1,s*nfft-nb)]),...
                   fft([a zeros(1,s*nfft-na)])).';
```

example:

```
x = fft([1.5,0,1,0,0,0,1,3]')

x =

   6.5000          
   3.6213 + 2.1213i
  -0.5000 + 3.0000i
  -0.6213 + 2.1213i
   0.5000          
  -0.6213 - 2.1213i
  -0.5000 - 3.0000i
   3.6213 - 2.1213i
```

now

```
y = fft([1,1,2,3,1,0,9,3]')

y =

20.0000          
 0.7071 + 6.2929i
-9.0000 + 5.0000i
-0.7071 - 7.7071i
 6.0000          
-0.7071 + 7.7071i
-9.0000 - 5.0000i
 0.7071 - 6.2929i
```

not really matter the fft's I need how to perfom this operation..

```
z = (x./y)

z =

   0.3250          
   0.3968 - 0.5309i
   0.1840 - 0.2311i
  -0.2656 - 0.1050i
   0.0833          
  -0.2656 + 0.1050i
   0.1840 + 0.2311i
   0.3968 + 0.5309i
```

I need an algorythm (no matlab code), I need something Java, or step by step calculus...

```
» a

a =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 4.0000i   5.0000 + 6.0000i        0          

» b

b =

   5.0000 + 2.0000i   1.0000 - 2.0000i        0                  0          

» c = a./b
Warning: Divide by zero.

c =

   0.3103 + 0.2759i  -1.0000 + 2.0000i      Inf +    Infi      NaN -    NaNi

»
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do division with complex numbers? The operator `./` just does element-wise division (`x[i] / y[i]`)

Comment: yes, I want to know the algorythm to perform this "./" operation (without matlab) with complex numbers.... like the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `./` operator performs element-wise division. You can tell it's an element-wise operator from the `.` before the division sign. This means that the result will be a vector with elements that are obtained using the rule `x[i] / y[i]`.

If you want to do this in Java you will either need to implement your own `Complex` number class writing the [division code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division) yourself, or you can use the **Apache commons math**  [`Complex`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html) class.

Assuming you use apache commons, the element-wise division in Java would look like this:

```
List<Complex> elementWiseDivision(List<Complex> dividend, List<Complex> divisor) 
{
  if (dividend.size() != divisor.size()) 
  { 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have same size"); 
  }
  List<Complex> result = new ArrayList<>();
  // using iterators to get O(n) with both LinkedList and ArrayList inputs
  for (Iterator<Complex> xit = dividend.iterator(), yit = divisor.iterator(); xit.hasNext();) 
  {
    result.add(xit.next().divide(yit.next()));
  }
  return result;
}
```